# Where to get UK city boundaries?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, united-kingdom

Currently I am working on a project where I have to draw boundaries of specific region of UK. Exactly like this

[image]

I want to know where to retrieve this kind of GIS data. I have tried openstreetmap data for uk, in that some of the data are unavailable for UK cities.

Comment: OSM does have cities in the administrative boundaries levels https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8117/getting-city-border-from-osm-data

Comment: OpenData from Ordnance Survey (Boundary Line) will have City Boundaries https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html (Only England, Wales and Scotland GB not UK which includes Northern Ireland) this will be in OSGB36 National Grid Projection and only linework (polygons will have to be generated)

Comment: Thank you Mapperz, I found the British .shp file. How to extract polygon data from that file.

Comment: Using a GIS like QGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30765/create-polygon-layer-from-polyline-layer

Comment: Hello I have successfully downloaded and converted that shapefile to .kml file. Now I want to know how to read city boundaries from that file in C#. I have been finding this past three days but no result.

Comment: that is another question... create a new one.