# Merging polygon and line shapefiles into one using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge

I have two shapefiles: One is a line feature of the rivers and waterways of London, the other is a polygon feature of the reservoirs, lakes and ponds of the same area.

Is it possible please to merge these two different shapefiles into one using QGIS?

Comment: Shapefiles can only hold one geometry type: point, polygon, line. Either convert the river lines to polygons (buffer perhaps) or the lakes/reservoirs to bounding lines and then you can merge.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Probably should make that an answer. I'm sure this question is a duplicate of one somewhere, but ten minutes of searching hasn't found me one.

Comment: @ChrisW, I thought I'd seen it before too but also couldn't find it. I've put in an answer with some references to substantiate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Converting the river lines to polygons has enabled me to merge the two layers.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [shapefile specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) (page 4):

> All the non-Null shapes in a shapefile are required to be of the same
>   shape type. The values for shape type are as follows:

```
Value Shape Type
0 Null Shape 
1 Point 
3 PolyLine 
5 Polygon 
8 MultiPoint 
11 PointZ 
13 PolyLineZ 
15 PolygonZ 
18 MultiPointZ 
21 PointM 
23 PolyLineM 
25 PolygonM 
28 MultiPointM
```

This means that either all the shapes in the shapefile are polygon (5,15 or 25) or polyline (3, 13 or 23), in order to merge these you can either [Convert the polygons in the reservoirs to lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/how-can-i-transform-a-polygon-to-a-linestring-in-qgis), [convert the lines to polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30765/create-polygon-layer-from-polyline-layer) or [buffer the lines to make polygons](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html). When they are the same geometry type then you can [merge the shapefiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-to-merge-multiple-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis).

Comment: Thank you for your response, much appreciated. This has clarified the issues of differing geometry. Many thanks.